# Clone and Remove Method efficiently if possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I hope that someone can help me please.

I need for the hidden text to be cloned and have the clone be removed regardless of the the status of the hidden text. Right now the Hidden text will show and when cloned, it produces the clone but the remove function does not work on the clone. Instead the remove function of the text that the duplicate was cloned from affects the clone. I would like for the Clone copy to hold the same events as the hidden text but independent of the status it was copied from.

I am trying to figure out how to use the cloning and remove methods with a table I am building. I have searched online with .data(array[1]) and .hide and .show. but in order for my idea to work I NEED to use the remove and clone if possible!

I APPRECIATE IT!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var count = 1;
var $clone = $(".t1").clone(true)
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide0").click(function(){
        $(".t0").hide();
    });
    $(".show0").click(function(){
        $(".t1 , .t0").show();
    });

    $(".hide1").click(function(){
        $(".t1").remove();
    });
    $(".show1").click(function(){
    if(count < 2) {
        $(".t1").clone(false).appendTo("body");

        count++;
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="t0">Original Text. <br /></div>
<button class="show0">Add Project</button>
<br />

<div class="t1" style="color:red; display:none;">
Hidden Text when removed, clone copy is removed and cannot be regenerated. Clone copy should hold the same events as the original but independent of the status it was copied from. <br>
<button class="show1">Add Project</button>
<button class="hide1">Remove Project</button><br /></div>

<div class="t2" style="color:blue; display:none;">
If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.<br>
<button class="hide2">Remove Project</button><br /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle for a visual: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dbALiksKfi

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish, what output your code produces, and what you expected it to do.

Comment: I need for the hidden text to be cloned and have the clone be removed regardless of the the status of the hidden text. Right now the Hidden text will show and when cloned, it produces the clone but the remove function does not work on the clone. Instead the remove function of the text that the duplicate was cloned from affects the clone. I would like for the Clone copy to hold the same events as the hidden text but independent of the status it was copied from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is how to handle events for dynamically created elements (in this case button add and remove in t1 class).

**Code**

```
  $(document).on("click", ".show1", function(e) {

    if ($(".t1").length < MaxRows) {
      addRows();
    }

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".hide1", function(e) {

    $(this).parent(".t1").remove();

  });
```

And the second problem is cloning elements. It will be easier if you do the following:

- create a div named `original`
- clone this `original`
- change `original` class name to `t1`
- append it to a `row` or `container` class to hold your clones

**Code**

```
function addRows() {

  $(".t1-original")
    .clone(false)
    .removeClass("t1-original")
    .addClass("t1")
    .appendTo(".data-rows")
    .show()
    .find(".name").html(new Date().toISOString() + " <br/>");

}
```

```js
var MaxRows = 3;

function addRows() {

  $(".t1-original")
    .clone(false)
    .removeClass("t1-original")
    .addClass("t1")
    .appendTo(".data-rows")
    .show()
    .find(".name").html(new Date().toISOString() + " <br/>");

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".show0").click(function() {
    // $(".t1 , .t0").show();
    if ($(".t1").length < MaxRows) {
   addRows();
    }
  });

  // .hide0 class does not exist?
  $(".hide0").click(function() {
    $(".t0").hide();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".show1", function(e) {

    if ($(".t1").length < MaxRows) {
      addRows();
    }

  });

  $(document).on("click", ".hide1", function(e) {

    $(this).parent(".t1").remove();

  });

  // $(".hide1").click(function() {
  //   $(".t1").remove();
  // });

  //$(".show1").click(function() {
  //  if (count < 3) {
  //    $(".t1").clone(false).appendTo("body");
  //
  //    count++;
  //  }
  //});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t0">
  Original Text.
  <br />
</div>

<button class="show0">Add Project</button>
<br />

<div class="t1-original" style="color:red; display:none;">
  <span class="name"></span> Hidden Text when removed, clone copy is removed and cannot be regenerated. Clone copy should hold the same events as the original but independent of the status it was copied from.
  <br>

  <button class="show1">Add Project</button>
  <button class="hide1">Remove Project</button>
  <br />
</div>

<div class="data-rows">

</div>

<div class="t2" style="color:blue; display:none;">
  If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.
  <br>

  <button class="hide2">Remove Project</button>
  <br />
</div>
```